# MySQL on Windows - Questions about binaries

Tags: windows, mysql, services

I'm trying to gather identifying information for processes running on Windows.
I've been unable to discover the difference between the 'mysqld.exe' and 'mysqld-nt.exe' binaries. What is the difference, and what functions are supplied by each?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on myresearch one is the demon and the other the windows-nt service.  Unless you have MySQL installed you should just end the process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are the same thing, the background service (aka Daemon) that is the MySQL program/interface.

From my understanding the "-nt" was dropped from the Windows versions (renamed to just Mysqld.exe) sometime around version 5 of MySQL.

I have no source to cite unfortunately, but our MySQL servers run 5.x on them, and none of them have a mysqld-nt.exe files on them, but I know I've seen it in the (distant) past.

Comment: I'm looking specifically at MySQL 5.0 here, and I think you're right in that they dropped the '-nt' after this version. I'm seeing both processes running at the same time though. I think Ramhound, above, was right in that the 'mysqld.exe' is the server itself whereas the 'mysqld-nt.exe' is the Microsoft service. I would like to verify that though.

Comment: We don't have an "-nt" version running, nor do we even have the file at all on our 5.5 servers (that I could find).  Perhaps there's more than one instance/version of MySQL running on the machine?  Embedded DB in a program maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference: `mysqld-nt.exe` was a version of MySQL that took advantage of a specific Windows Communication Protocol called Named Pipes.

According to the [the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127)

[image]

Chapter 23 Pages 352,353 under the Section entitled "23.2 Communication Protocols"

Bulletpoint #3 says

> Named-pipe conventions are supported only on Windows and only if you use one of the server that has the `-nt` in its name (mysql-nt, mysql-max-nt). However, named pipes are disabled by default. To enable named-pipe connections, you must start the `-nt` server with the `--enable-named-pipe` option.

This is how the book presents it. I think it is a typo. The part that says `(mysql-nt, mysql-max-nt)` should say `(mysqld-nt, mysqld-max-nt)`. Nevertheless, using named pipes was probably used as an alternative to doing localhost host connections in Windows.

I wrote a post 3 years ago in the DBA StackExchange ([**MySQL-NT is crashing frequently**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6227/877)) discussing how one should get away from it, especially since [**it went EOL April 2011**](http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html).

If you are running `mysqld-nt.exe` and you did not know about [--enable-named-pipe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_enable-named-pipe) option, the named pipe is not enabled (default). Therefore, `mysqld-nt.exe` would behave exactly like `mysqld.exe`. I would still get away from it and just use `mysqld.exe`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I'm not actually running MySQL (not on Windows at any rate), but rather trying to systemically build an inventory of software running on Windows servers through process information pulled through WMI. Are there any differences between the two services, especially in the context of server dependency mapping?

Comment: Given the default protocols of each, there is no functional difference between mysqld.exe and mysqld-nt.exe. I still advise anyone to switch to mysqld.exe.